# Connect Domian to Ngnix

Tags: linux

so i installed nginx and config it like this :

```
 server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
 server_name example.com www.example.com;

 root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

 index index.html index.htm;

 location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
 }
```

and set dns server to my domian :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0OQ1.png)

its work

but when try to connet domian i got error
:
Unable to connect

An error occurred during a connection to example.com.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic]: Your question doesn't look like it's on-topic on stackoverflow, as it's not programming related.. Note: An edit of the question _could_ make it on-topic again...